# Good DropDownList or ComboBox auto complete filtering control

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am looking for a good DropDownList or ComboBox that I can use that will allow the user to enter data and have the values in the DDL be dynamically filtered.

I am a Javascript NOVICE, but most solutions probably use Javascript (as long as I don't need to know about the man behind he curtain, that is fine I suppose...lol).

Comment: what do you mean by "allow use to enter data" - do you mean to select a value or you want use to add values?

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of autocomplete:

- Autocomplete with static data, in which items are **populated on load** and **filtered on demand**
- Ajax autocomplete, in which items are **populated and filtered on demand**.

Static autocomplete is suitable for small datasets that do not burden the page load too much. Ajax autocomplete is better for large datasets, but imposes a latency due to an Ajax request. My experience is that Ajax autocomplete is best implemented with a popular client-side control, such as [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), instead of a proprietary ASP.NET control. The reason is that compatibility and support are better for popular client-side controls, and you should be able find solutions to your particular requirements. With ASP.NET controls, you are more likely to end up on your own.

This said, there are ASP.NET controls such as the free [ComboBox](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/combobox/combobox.aspx) and [AutoCompleteExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) that come with ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit, and commercial controls like Telerik [RadComboBox](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) and DevExpress [ASPxComboBox](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxEditorsDemos/ASPxComboBox/LargeDataSource.aspx). All are good for non-ajax autocomplete, and easier to populate with data than jquery UI autocomplete. With Ajax requests, I had trouble getting Telerik RadComboBox work without trouble, and switched to jQuery UI autocomplete. But with static data, I still use RadComboBox and ASPxComboBox.

One thing to remember with ASP.NET combobox controls is that ViewState takes a lot of space with any larger datasets, if it is enabled. Postbacks make more trouble than page loads, since users have usually less upload bandwidth than download bandwidth. With Telerik RadComboBox, I used to disable viewstate when using ajax on-demand autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using jQuery UI's autocomplete control:

- jQuery: http://jquery.com/
- Demo: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

If you're unhappy with the jQuery UI control there are dozens of other autocomplete jQuery plugins that can be found [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/autocomplete%20type%3aproject_project).

Answer (score 0):

[check](http://www.devcurry.com/2011/05/jquery-editable-combo-box.html)
this. it may be helpful for your situation.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Shield UI's autocomplete [combobox widget](http://demos.shieldui.com/aspnet/combobox/remote-data) demo - it is a powerful component available for pure JavaScript, ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC.